# When will cellChanged signal be fired in QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a QTableWidget to display and edit a data matrix. For validation purpose, I used the QLineEdit as items in this table. As following,

```
        pTable=new QTableWidget(N,N,this);
        pItem=new QLineEdit();
        pItem->setText(tr("%1").arg(pInfra->adjacencyM(i,j)));
        rx=new QRegExp("0|1");
        validatorRegexp=new QRegExpValidator(*rx,0);
        pItem->setValidator(validatorRegexp);
        pTable->setCellWidget(i,j,pItem);
```

Since I want to know if data in certain cell has been changed, so I tried cellChanged(int, int) signal, and connect it with my own slot cellEdited(int,int), like this

```
connect(pTable,SIGNAL(cellChanged(int,int)),this, SLOT(cellEdited(int,int)));
```

But, when I edit QLineEdit in the cell, I can not catch this signal. When will this signal be fired? Or can I do this using another signal or in some other way? 
Thanks!

Comment: Not aware about causes of this problem. Considering another ways. You can catch `QLineEdit` signal `textChanged` and use [QSignalMapper](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qsignalmapper.html) to bind signal, fired by each `QLineEdit` to particular cell number. Maybe itsn't the best qway to do that, but you can use it in case this problem won't be solved.

Comment: Thank you, beduin, I used QSignalMapper, and it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not aware about causes of this problem. Considering another ways. You can catch `QLineEdit` signal `textChanged` and use [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsignalmapper.html) to bind signal, fired by each `QLineEdit` to particular cell number. Maybe itsn't the best qway to do that, but you can use it in case this problem won't be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `cellChanged()` signal is emittet only if the table model is issued the `setData()` method, which normally comes from the `QLineEdit` of the delegate. Since You have your own mechanism by setting the cell widget the `setData()` method of the model will never be called. Which means you'll have to connect to the `textChanged()` or the `textEdited()` signal of the `QLineEdit` object you put in the cells.

Another valid option is the approach mentioned by beduin in the comment.

Also possible: You could subclass the used delegate and make it create `QLineEdit` objects with your validator. Which would be the cleanest approach since you don't interfere with the model/view architecture and can rely on the signals the table object is sending.

Best regards
D

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that I did not follow the model/view framework. Since I did not want to subclass, I will try beduin's method first.