# PyQt5: How to get the signal from a QTableWidget with QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I understand this is a beginner's question, I searched but could not found the answer.

In the App there is a `QTableWidget`, which contains a `QComboBox`, a `QDoubleSpinBox`, and some regualar items.

By changing **ANY** cells I want to have the method `on_change` activated and print something.

The code below doesnot take the change-signal from the `QComboBox` and `QDoubleSpinBox`. How could I correct the code?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

list_text = ["a", "b", "c"]

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.createTable()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.show()

    def createTable(self):
        # Create table
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Text0"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Text1"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Text2"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Text3"))

        self.cbx = QComboBox()
        self.cbx.addItems(list_text)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(2, 0, self.cbx)


        self.dsb = QDoubleSpinBox(self)
        self.dsb.setDecimals(0)
        self.dsb.setMinimum(1)
        self.dsb.setMaximum(100)
        self.dsb.setSingleStep(1)
        self.dsb.setValue(50)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(3, 0, self.dsb)


        # table selection change
        self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.on_change)

    def on_change(self):
        print("any item was changed. ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe try connecting the `QComboBox` and `QComboBox` widgets to the slot you want. something like `self.cbx.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_change)`. You have however to be careful about the argument types of function `on_change`.

Comment: @GergesDib Thanks for the help. It works with your method. However I actually prefer to generate the signal from QTableWidget directly, because my App is quite complex. :-(

Comment: In this case, you might be better off with a qtableview and build your own model/delegates. There is also some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892420/when-will-cellchanged-signal-be-fired-in-qtablewidget)

Comment: @LucasMeier. Changes to cell **widgets** do not change cell **items**, so there is never any reason for the `itemChanged` signal to be emitted (and the same goes for all other table-widget signals). Item delegates are probably what you need, because they can directly update item data (and thus avoid the need for intermediary signals from cell widgets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "change the item", you change "the items content", when switching something on the `QCombobox` or `QSpinbox`.

Therefore, they need their own connection:

```
# table selection change
self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.on_change)    
# adding with this
self.dsb.valueChanged.connect(self.on_change)
self.cbx.currentTextChanged.connect(self.on_change)
```

If you were adding something new to the basic cell, the signal would get triggered, but in your setup there is just an object in the cell, that is not changing at all (because it's child is doing so).